# Resize an AlertDialog Icon from Dynamic BitMap

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, icons, android-alertdialog

As of Android 19 (KITKAT), I'm no longer able to resize the icon in an AlertDialog, dynamically, in code. It has worked in Android 8 - 16. Now, it just shows the icon at its original width and height -- not the resized one.

Note that these images are downloaded from my server on the fly, and the same dialog will show a different image depending upon choices made by the user.

Here's what used to work for me. Any suggestions on how to update it for Android 19+?

*Note: I have tried Bitmap.createScaledBitmap solution (see commented out lines). It has no effect.*

```
Uri downloadedIcon = Uri.parse( "file://" + filePath );
BitMap bm = Media.getBitmap( getContentResolver(), downloadedIcon );

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();        
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);  
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

if (width >= 2000) {
    bm.setDensity(840);
    //bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,920,920,true);
} else if (width >= 1440) {
    bm.setDensity(640);
    //bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,700,700,true);
} else if(width >= 1024)
    // etc
}

BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(bm);

AlertDialog theAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
.setTitle("My Title")
.setMessage("My Description")
.setIcon(-1).setIcon(icon)
theAlert.show();
```

Comment: can you show images of expected and actual result? is 840x640 your target size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by creating my own dialog layout.

The problem is that in Android 19+, the default (system) dialog layout will forcibly shrink the icon's src. So to make it large -- you need to forget about the icon, and stop using it. Instead, define a new ImageView in your own custom layout.

custom_dialog.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_pic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>   

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:text="DESCRIPTION GOES HERE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="17sp" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

After inflating the ImageView, I override it with my dynamic BitMap, like this:

```
Uri downloadedIcon = Uri.parse( "file://" + filePath );
BitMap bm = Media.getBitmap( getContentResolver(), downloadedIcon );

View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_custom_dialog, null);
ImageView pic = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_pic);
pic.setImageBitmap( bm );
TextView desc = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
desc.setText("My Description Text");

AlertDialog theAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScriptMenuActivity.this)
    .setView(dialogView)
    .setTitle("My Title Text")
    .setNegativeButton("Back", null)
    .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // do stuff
        }}).create();
    theAlert.show();
```

The dialog pic is resized proportionately to fit the dialog window, automatically, through the ImageView's 'adjustViewBounds' and 'scaleType' attributes.